# Late 2011 Macbook with Windows 10 - adjustable brightness with main video card?

Tags: laptop, drivers, macbook

I recently installed Windows 10 on my late 2011 MBP. All is well, but screen brightness doesn't seem to work with the main video card driver (ATI 6600M) - changing the slider on the UI or with button don't have an effect.
If I change the card driver to Microsoft Basic Display, the slider works, but the max brightness is around 50% and I suspect only the slow onboard video is active.

Is there a way to get brightness working with the primary ATI card being active?

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't, as that's an unsupported Mac model for Win 10, so there are no hardware-specific drivers from Boot Camp.

You might try AMD themselves for drivers, but I'd have a backup ready, just in case.

That card has also been legacied by AMD, so this is the latest *[& last ever]* driver set for it - http://support.amd.com/en-us/download/desktop/legacy?product=legacy3&os=Windows%2010%20-%2064 (Win 10 64-bit, specifically)

Answer (score 0):

I just had to install the Cataclyst driver from the Bootcamp 6.0 package. After updating Cataclyst, brightness control now works as expected.